# Adding a list item within another list

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

Ok I have a class similar to the following...

```
public class Order
{
    private Guid id;
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private List<Items> orderItems;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Items> OrderItems
    {
        get { return orderItems; }
        set { orderItems= value; }
    }

}

public class Items
{
    private string itemName;
    [DataMember]
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return itemName; }
        set { itemName = value; }
    }

}
```

When I reference in my code I have a method that takes in an "Order" list as the parameter.

```
ACME.Order newOrder = new ACME.Order();
ACME.Items newItems = new ACME.Items();

newOrder.ID = xxx
newItems.ItemName = xxx

SendOrderWithItemsFunction(newOrder)
```

The above works fine however I don't have an add function for my items so that I can do something like the following

```
newOrder.Items.Add(newItem);
```

and

```
newOrder.Items = newItems
```

will not work because it says that it can not implicitly convert newOrder.Items to newItems[].

What am Missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I might be missing something, but `newOrder.OrderItems.Add(newItem)` should work just fine, according to waht you have in your post.

Just some other nitpick things:

The pluralization of the "Items" class is wierd, if it is only a single Item.  This is probably the reason that it looked "ok" to assign a single item to a List property.

You may have cut it out of your post, but every class that is being serialized by WCF must be marked as a "DataContract", not just the members of the class.

When initializing objects like this, I think it makes it a lot cleaer to use [Type Initializers](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/187116.aspx):

```
var NewOrder = new ACME.Order{
     ID = xxx,
     OrderItems = new List<ACME.Item>
     {
          new ACME.Item{
               ItemName = xxx
          }
     }
};
```

Comment: Great point about the pluralization, I'll definitely make that change.  Also I do have the datacontract information I just cut it out as you said to keep the example clean.  

However my issue is that I don't have the Add function available to me in intelisense.  All I have are things like Any<>, Aggregate<> and so on which leads me to believe that I am missing something but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
newOrder.OrderItems.Add(newItem);
```

If your newItems[] is an array, you need to do this:

```
newOrder.OrderItems.AddRange(newItem.ToList<Items>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `newItems` as an `ACME.Items` type, but the `OrderItems` property of your `Order` class is a `List<Items>`.  Those types are not assignable from one to the other directly.  So, an assignment of `newOrder.OrderItems = newItems` is like trying to say`List<Items> = Items`.  That isn't possible based on the classes you outlined above.  Instead, you will need to add to the list.

Answer (score 0):

What you do have is an add function in your `Order.OrderItems` property:

```
newOrder.OrderItems.Add(newItem);
```

you can even add a whole list of items to your OrderItems:

```
var someList = new List<Items>();
//populate someList here
newOrder.OrderItems.AddRange(someList);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a list within a list, and the Add() method is missing, a workaround is to make a new list, add the items, then set the inner list to the new list. Instead of:

```
outerList.innerList.Add(item)
```

..use..

```
var newList = new List<ItemType>();
newList.Add(item);
outerList.innerList = newList;
```